# Search text file and find replace dictionary keys with values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to put together a program that will search the contents of an entire text file.  The program would search the text file against a dictionary and replace any key found with its dictionary value.  I am running into an error and I am unsure how to proceed.

example:
dictionary = {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3 etc...}

random text example:
Before
Over fact all Key1 tell this any his. Key1 insisted confined of weddings Key2 returned Key3 debating rendered.

After
Over fact all Value1 tell this any his. Value1 insisted confined of weddings Value2 returned Value3 debating rendered.

```
mappings = {
100: 1500, 101: 1501, 103: 1502, 106: 1503, 117: 1504, 120: 1505, 121: 1506, 122: 1507, 123: 1508, 124: 1509,
125: 1510, 126: 1511, 127: 1512, 128: 1513, 129: 1514, 130: 1515, 131: 1516, 132: 1517, 133: 1518, 134: 1519,
150: 1520, 152: 1521, 153: 1522, 154: 1523, 160: 1524, 161: 1525, 170: 1526, 171: 1527, 200: 1528, 209: 1529,
211: 1530, 223: 1531, 224: 1532, 231: 1533, 241: 1534, 242: 1535, 243: 1536, 244: 1537, 245: 1538, 246: 1539,
248: 1540, 249: 1541, 264: 1542, 284: 1543, 285: 1544, 290: 1545, 298: 1546, 299: 1547, 300: 1548, 301: 1549,
302: 1550, 303: 1551, 304: 1552, 305: 1553, 310: 1554, 320: 1555, 321: 1556, 322: 1557, 323: 1558, 324: 1559,
328: 1560, 340: 1561, 341: 1562, 342: 1563, 343: 1564, 344: 1565, 345: 1566, 346: 1567, 347: 1568, 360: 1569,
361: 1570, 362: 1571, 363: 1572, 364: 1573, 366: 1574, 367: 1575, 368: 1576, 369: 1577, 370: 1578, 371: 1579,
372: 1580, 376: 1581, 385: 1582, 386: 1583, 387: 1584, 388: 1585, 389: 1586, 395: 1587, 396: 1588, 397: 1589,
398: 1590, 399: 1591, 3000: 1325, 3001: 1326, 400: 1592, 401: 1593, 402: 1594, 403: 1595, 404: 1596, 405: 1597,
406: 1598, 407: 1599, 408: 1300, 450: 1301, 451: 1302, 452: 1303, 453: 1304, 454: 1305, 455: 1306, 500: 1307,
501: 1308, 502: 1309, 503: 1310, 504: 1311, 505: 1312, 506: 1313, 507: 1314, 508: 1315, 509: 1316, 600: 1317,
601: 1318, 602: 1319, 603: 1320, 604: 1321, 605: 1322, 606: 1323, 614: 1324, 700: 3728, 701: 3729, 702: 3730,
750: 3731, 751: 3732, 752: 3733, 800: 3734, 801: 3735, 802: 3736, 803: 3737, 805: 3738, 806: 3739, 807: 3740,
808: 3741, 809: 3742, 900: 3743, 902: 3744, 915: 3745, 920: 3746
}

# Open file for substitution
replaceFile = open('as03_int.txt', 'r+')

# read in all the lines
lines = replaceFile.readlines()

# seek to the start of the file and truncate
replaceFile.seek(0)
replaceFile.truncate()

# Loop through each line from file
for line in lines:
    # Loop through each Key in the mappings dict
    for i in mappings.keys():
        # if the key appears in the line
        if i in line:
            print(line)
            # do replacement
            line = line.replace(i, mappings[i])
    # Print the line and move to next line
    print(line)
```

```
    if i in line:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear... What are you confused about? Please [edit] to clarify. As well, it would help to provide a [mre]. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: To be clear, you're comparing strings to ints, which is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

You should use this corrected part of the code:

```
......
for i in mapping.keys():
    if str(i) in line:
        ......
```

Comment: Alternatively you could convert the dictionary values into strings instead of ints before iterating over the text file.